# Something wrong , sending post request using jquery.post()

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, request, xmlhttprequest, .post

I have a file that's called camera.php, here is the source bellow :

camera.php

```
    <div id="video" style="margin: auto;text-align:center;">
            <video autoplay id="vid"></video>
    </div>
        <button id="start" class="btn" onclick="Start()">Start</button>
        <button id="stop" class="btn" onclick="Stop()">Stop</button>
        <button id="takeshot" class="btn" onclick="TakeShot()">TakeShot</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        video = document.getElementById('vid');

        function Start() {
            if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video : true}).then((stream) => {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                });
            }
            else
                console.log('ur navigator does not support getUserMedia !!');
        }

        function Stop() {
            if (video.srcObject)
                video.srcObject = undefined;
        }
        function TakeShot() {
            if (video.srcObject) {
                canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                gtc = canvas.getContext('2d');
                gtc.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
                imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                //gtc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                pb = document.getElementById('pb').value;
                pub(imgData, pb);
            }
            else
                console.log('you need to use Webcam to take a shot');
        }
        function pub(img, pb) {
          // using jquery.post() to send request
           $.post('https://xxxxxx.com/camera/save', {'img' : img, 'pub' : pb, 'stick' : stickSelectd}, (result) => {
                 obj = JSON.parse(result);
                 if (obj.error == true) {
                     document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = obj.msg;
                 }
                 else
                     document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Publication has been added';
             }).done(() => {
                 alert('request is done');
             }).fail(() => {
                 alert('request is fail');
            });
         // using jquery.ajax() to send post request
            $.ajax({
                url : 'https://xxxxxx.com/camera/save',
                method : 'POST',
                data : {
                    'img' : img, 'pub' : pb, 'stick' : stickSelectd
                },
                headers : "Content-type : image/png",
                Success : (result) => {
                    alert(result);
                },
                err : () => {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

.htaccess
I know too many risks for allow-origin "*" but i use it just for testing.

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

always request sending by $.post() alert 'request is fail' and sometimes the request is received from the server and save the image but the meme respond is getting ('request is fail').

there is all fine in my code or i miss something like headers, .. ??
and thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

it works now with ajax(), i change the function pub to :

```
function pub(img, pb) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'https://xxxxxxxx.com/camera/save',
                method : 'POST',
                data : {
                    'img' : img, 'pub' : pb, 'stick' : stickSelectd
                },
                headers : "Content-type : image/png"
            }).done((result) => {
                obj = JSON.parse(result);
                if (obj.error == true) {
                    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = obj.msg;
                }
                else
                    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Publication has been added';
            }).fail(() => {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'something wrong !! try again';
            })
        }
```

i don't know why the old syntax doesn't work, I think it fine ?!